# Problem with ADF Dataflow pipeline when writing data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF Dataflow pipeline that reads data from a data lake and writes it to a SQL Server table. I have a problematic column called "gdtxft" that I converted from binary to string using the 'toString' function in the Derived column setting. The column has a size of nvarchar(max) in SQL Server.

The problem is that when ADF Dataflow writes to SQL Server, it only writes the first character in the string and when I save the results using Excel, I can see all the string characters. I have verified that the data is being stored correctly in SQL Server by running queries on the table.

I have also checked the pipeline settings and verified that the correct encoding is being used and that the data is being read and written correctly. I have tried reading the data from the source using other tools and comparing the results with the data in SQL Server, but I haven't found any differences.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to convert binary column to string using 'toString' function in the Derived column setting in ADF Dataflow pipeline, expecting the complete string to be written to SQL Server table, but the pipeline only wrote the first character of the string.

Comment: This has nothing to do with collations and encoding. You can't just call `ToString()` on a PNG image, a ZIP package or MP3 file and get a useful string. You need to find out what `gdtxft` really contains, what format is used and whether there's any text to retrieve from it first

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I have been able to transfer the data using Databricks by casting the column "gdtxft" as string and the data transferred correctly without any issues. However, when using ADF Dataflow pipeline, the problem occurs. I will investigate further to find the root cause of the problem in the ADF Dataflow pipeline and try to find a solution. I would greatly appreciate your guidance on how to proceed.